# How do you display results data from a query

Tags: sql, names

I am running the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT
    TS_MESSAGE,
    TX_SERVICENAME,
    TX_CONFIRMATION "Conf",
    TX_SS_MESSAGE,
    TX_OMS_MESSAGE,
    a.fl_resend_message
    from INTF_OMS.LOG_WEB_SERVICE_SS_INITIATED a
    where tx_servicename like '%mobileUserForcedToSignOff%' 
    --and tx_ss_message like '%e50702%'
    and tx_ss_message  like '%E30046%'
    and a.ts_message like '%25-JAN-11%'
    order by ts_message asc
```

I get the results I want, however the columns tx_ss_message contains the following information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MobileUserForcedToSignOff>
  <MessageId></MessageId>
  <MessageDate>20110125</MessageDate>
  <MessageTime>1853</MessageTime>
  <DispatchUserId>E30046</DispatchUserId>
  <MobileUserId>e19952</MobileUserId>
</MobileUserForcedToSignOff>
```

What I really want, is when I run the query, is for it to return ONLY The DispatchUserID, MessageDate, and MobileUserID.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Write a query outside the one you already have that parses the xml for the 3 items you want